# Prove that the equation has only one real root.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $(x-1)^3+(x-2)^3+(x-3)^3+(x-4)^3=0$ has **only one** real root.
It's easy to show that the equation has a real root using Rolle's theorem. But how to show that the real root is unique? By Descartes' rule of sign, it can be shown that it has 3 or 1 real root.

But it doesn't guarantee that the real root is unique. If we calculate the root then it can be shown that it has only one real root.

Comment: The function is strictly increasing.   If $x_1 > x_0$ then $x_1 - c > x_0 -c$ and $(x_1 -c)^3 > (x_0 -c)^3$ and $\sum (x_1 -c)^3 > \sum (x_0 - c)^3$.

Comment: The real root also has multiplicity 1.

Comment: More simply, it's strictly increasing because it's the sum of four strictly increasing functions.

Answer (score 30):

The function is strictly increasing so the function is one to one.

Answer (score 30):

A solution that only uses school algebra:

Substitute $t=x-5/2$. Then the equation becomes
$$(t+3/2)^3+(t+1/2)^3+(t-1/2)^3+(t-3/2)^3=0.$$
Expanding the brackets, we get 
$$4t^3+15t=0,$$
or $t(4t^2+15)=0$,
which clearly only has one real root.

Comment: Good and simple answer so have my +1, but do you have any intuition why one should use the transformation t=x-5/2 and not something else?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum To exploit the symmetry of the four terms around $x-5/2$. 5/2 is the average of 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @EvangelosBampas Indeed, but that is not mentioned in the answer and the transformation comes a bit out of the blue

Answer (score 15):

**Hint**:

It is the sum of four increasing functions, and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}=-\infty$,  $\lim_{x\to+\infty}=+\infty$. The *intermediate value theorem* guarantees there is a root, and monotonicity ensures there can be no more than one.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a rather primitive solution (although judging by the contents of your question you may already know this):

By symmetry, we can see that $x=2.5$ is a real root.  We want to show that it is the only real root.  Expanding the binomial cubes, we get $$4x^3-30x^2+90x-100$$
which factors into $$2(2x-5)(x^2-5x+10).$$

As the discriminant of the quadratic factor is negative, this tells us that $x=2.5$ is the only real root.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Can you show the derivative is positive for all $x$?

Thus, the function is strictly increasing for all $x$.

$x=2.5$ is a root.

Comment: Is the derivative really necessary here?

Comment: I suppose it is one way to _show_ that a function is strictly increasing.

Comment: and a fairly straightforward way in this case, though it's not really necessary

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\dfrac{x-1+x-2+x-3+x-4}4$

$x=y+2.5$

$$(x-1)^3+(x-2)^3+(x-3)^3+(x-4)^3=(y+1.5)^3+(y+.5)^3+(y-.5)^3+(y-1.5)^3$$

Now use $(a-b)^3+(a+b)^3=2(a^3+3ab^2)$

$$0=4y^3+6y((1.5)^2+(.5)^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary way that uses only

- $(1)$: $a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ and
- $(2)$: $a^2+b^2 >ab$ for $|a|+|b| > 0$

Note, that $|x-1|+|x-4|\geq |x-1 +(4-x)| =3 > 0$ and $|x-2|+|x-3|\geq |x-2 +(3-x)| =1 > 0$

Let's call $p(x) = (x-1)^3+ (x-2)^3 + (x-3)^3 + (x-4)^3$.

Now, using $(1)$ write
$$(x-1)^3 + (x-4)^3 = (x-1 + x-4)\left((x-1)^2 + (x-4)^2 - (x-1)(x-4)\right)$$
$$= (2x-5)\left((x-1)^2 + (x-4)^2 - (x-1)(x-4)\right)$$
$$(x-2)^3 + (x-3)^3 = (x-2 + x-3)\left((x-2)^2 + (x-3)^2 - (x-2)(x-3)\right)$$ $$= (2x-5)\left((x-2)^2 + (x-3)^2 - (x-2)(x-3)\right)$$

Hence,

$$p(x) =  $$
$$(2x-5)\color{blue}{\left(\underbrace{(x-1)^2 + (x-4)^2 - (x-1)(x-4)}_{\stackrel{(2)}{>}0} + \underbrace{(x-2)^2 + (x-3)^2 - (x-2)(x-3)}_{\stackrel{(2)}{>}0}\right)}
$$

So,

$$p(x) = (2x-5)\color{blue}{q(x)} \mbox{ with } \color{blue}{q(x)} > 0 \mbox{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $x\mapsto x^3$ is increasing, since $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$ and $x^2+xy+y^2=\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\geq 0$.

Shifting the domain of an increasing function does not change the fact that it is increasing, so also $x\mapsto (x-n)^3$ is increasing for all $n$.

Adding increasing functions results in another increasing function.

Thus, for all natural numbers $n$ the polynomial
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x-i)^3
$$
is increasing. Since it tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ and $-\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$, it follows that the polynomial has exactly one value at which it crosses the $x$-axis, that is, exactly one real root.